# Are there any issues with using Niceforms?

Tags: javascript, html, css, niceforms

I just came across [Niceforms](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/) and they look..well, nice. I was wondering if anyone has used these? Are they fully cross browser compatible? Are there any other issues?
[image]
<sub>(source: [emblematiq.com](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/01.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Says on Help page: Niceforms is fully compatible with most modern browsers: IE7+, Firefox2+, Safari3+, Opera9+, Chrome0.3+, Mozilla1.5+, Camino1.6+.  Not compatible with IE6 though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue in my opinion with any of these types of techniques is if the form relies upon the technique to function.

From looking at [their demo page](http://www.emblematiq.com/lab/niceforms/demo/v20/niceforms.html):

- With JavaScript disabled, the form still looks pretty much the same except for the nice styling for the actual form elements. The form still functions.
- With CSS and JavaScript disabled, the form is still usable and functions.

One potential issue I can see with them is if you have to support IE6 with the full styling. Of course - if you have that requirement, you have more problems than just this.